# gcp dataflow apache-beam problem. import another python file to main .py with code

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a problem when working on a gcp dataflow project.
I have created a dataflow pipeline code in python. It works well. I want to import this code file into another python code file with some classes and functions. If I just import it but not use it my whole code does not work.

Error text when I put a message in pub/sub topic :

> File "dataflow_simple.py", line 87, in process
>   NameError: global name 'pvalue' is not defined

What can I do to import another file with some classes and use it?

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to achieve ? If the goal is to have one file defining the functions and classes and another one defining the pipeline, then you should do it the other way around: import the functions from the file that contains the pipeline.

If this is indeed what you are trying to do, organize your files in this way, and add a setup.py:

```
Dataflow
|----my_module
     |----__init__.py
     |----functions.py
     |----classes.py
|----setup.py
|----my_pipe.py
```

Then in my_pipe.py:

```
from my_module.functions import ...
from my_module.classes import ...
```

Still in my_pipe.py, give the path to setup.py when building the pipeline. This will ensure that all files are copied when sending the job to Dataflow:

```
options = beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions(
    ...,
    setup_file='/path/to/setup.py')
```

[Reference](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#multiple-file-dependencies)

Comment: Make sure to install the latest apache-beam as older versions are buggy around the package feature. Use ```pip install -U apache-beam[gcp]```